# Transform condition to numeric 0 1

Tags: r

My datasheet d contain multiple covariates regarding a specific disease. One of them is "Age on diagnosis", which is coded as d$Age.

I want to make a new variable called "Age10" where Age < 10 (age below 10 years on time of diagnosis) is coded 0 and Age >= (age equal to or higher on time of diagnosis) is coded as 1.

I have tried subsetting without succes

Can you help?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example using `dput`. It's a lot easier to answer your question when the data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work:

```
d$Age10 <- as.numeric(d$Age >= 10)
```

Comment: It didnt - it says; Error `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Age10", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 72

Comment: The above code should work. This probably means that your column name is not "Age". Make sure it doesn't have any spaces. Try `names(d)` to check.

Comment: In such cases I prefer `as.integer` but like @AntoniosK says, your code is correct. This is a clear case of a question without data.

Comment: Thanks! It worked - Column name was not Age :)